# Unable to Install Google Play Services Package, rev. 11

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services

I opened the Android SDK Manager from Android Studio, and it prompts me to install a package – an update to Google Play services.
However, when I accept the license and click "Install", I get a dialogue with the following text: 
"Downloading Google Play services, revision 11
Download interrupted: URL not found.
Done. Nothing was installed."

I've tried restarting the SDK manager and Android Studio. 
I'm using the latest version of Android Studio, version 0.2.9.

What should I do to update?

Comment: My SDK manager does not show a rev 11 update to Google Play Services (currently have rev 10). It could be that they added it, but never put up the file (and have since removed the listing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same problem here, I am using Eclipse Kepler, seems to be an Android SDK Manager issue.

Answer (score 2):

I think the latest version is only V10 (as of 2013 Sept)
Seems there's a parsing error in [addon.xml](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml).

```
<sdk:revision>10</sdk:revision>
```

1) Go to this site:

http:// blog.csdn.net/gyming/article/details/8168166

(there's a space after 'http://", I cannot post > 1 links, pls join them)

and download "google_play_services_3225130_r10"

2) Extract it ("google-play-services") to : "~\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130729\sdk\extras\google" (replace "adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130729" to ur Eclipse path)

3) follow this to import:

https:// developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/intro#sample_code

(there's a space after 'https://", I cannot post > 1 links, pls join them)

4) To set up a project to use the Google Play services SDK:

https: //developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject

(there's a space after 'https://", I cannot post > 1 links, pls join them)

5) try at ur own risk.

Answer (score 2):

Google Play Services rev 12 is now available. Worth rechecking for updates.

Also don't forget (as I did) to remove the old Google Play Services from your Eclipse workspace, then import and copy the new version back into Eclipse and then build it.